# How to get generate WSDL using GroovyWS

Tags: web-services, tomcat, soap, groovy, groovyws

I am implementing SOAP web services for a commercial application, and I am using  GroovyWS to speed up the development.

But, when I deploy it on Tomcat, I am not using Grails, as the software has it's own J2EE framework, **so how I do I get it to react to wsdl requests?**

Do I need to write a groovy-based servlet?

Ideally I would like the WSDL generated upon request, so I can easily change the interface and see the change.

It seems I will miss the annotations that JAX-WS provides for, though, to help fine-tune the WSDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [example](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Publishing+a+web-service) web application, the WSDL can be retrieved as follows:

```
http://localhost:6980/MathService?wsdl
```

Comment: But if I am not using Grails, do I need to put something in web.xml in my webapps directory, for tomcat to redirect to MathService? Somehow Tomcat needs to know where to go.

Comment: You could add the standard *groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet* to your web.xml, so that the groovy script gets executed as a groovlet. 

The problem is that the class *groovyx.net.ws.WSServer* will startup another listener thread bound to another port on your server machine. Container within a container.....

Perhaps you'd be better off trying to decorate your Groovy classes using the standard JAX-WS annotations?

GroovyWS appears to be more useful as a client library than for server based programming

Comment: Your comment is probably the correct answer. I wrote the service in Java, but I expect that decorating Groovy with annotations would have had the same effect.